Finding a grading system that balances professors grade and other students points
I'm not an educator in math, and that's probably why I can't wrap my head around this problem, but I think the general question and challange will fit. I'm an educator in design (postgraduate level) and I'm trying to come up with a grading system for a group design project. Some key points:

Every person in the group receive the same grade at the end (I know it may seem unfair to some, but learning how to work in a design team and organize work is a key takeaway, so everybody gets the same grade), so a group may be understood as a whole entity to be graded.
I have identified 7 evaluation criteria (they may be 6 or 8 as well. I'm still working on it, but they will be a fixed and finite number) and I will tell students they are graded on them.
An important moment in the evaluation is the final presentation + design critique. I care both that they do a good project and that they gain ability to critique other designs, so I want the first group to present to the second one, and the second one to critique a bit their work. I want to take in account the opponent-group critique in my final grade for the presenting one.
Since students grading students can be uncomfortable, I was thinking they may distribute a fixed number (which number? less then 7?) of "tokens" or "bonus points" between the 7 criterias (max 1 per criteria or more?). In that way they will focus on rewarding what they think is virtuous (and then telling why during the critique) and not punishing what they find lacking. In other words, they'll implicitly create a hierarchy of the criteria based on what the presenting group did well but, if they are forced to use all the points, no antipathies will be created due to “you didn't vote for me enough”.

Now, I know it sounds rather complex, and that if I don't find a good way to do it with a fine system and a automated spreadsheet, I might as well switch to a completely qualitative approach and just take the criticism of the opponent-group into consideration when I evaluate a presenting-group. But I thought it would be worth a try to ask some more experienced people for ideas, opinions, and feedback.
Thanks!
Ps: ideally I would also like to evaluate the opponent-group's ability to critique, but I don't want to complicate things
Ps2: here the grading system is from 0 to 30 (+ optional "cum laude"), with 18 minimum to pass. But i guess every system works, then i map it to 30.

Hmm, as this is a question about education in design, I'm not quite sure why you ask it on the math educators stackexchange.

It's a question about education grading system. If we pretend the criterias are mathematical problems to be graded individually and the peer review is a "comment/bonus" on how elegant the solution process of choice is, the system would be simular, or am I wrong?

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about math education. Suggest it may be a better fit on SE Academia, possibly.

I would take a step back and ask what the goals are. You say that you want to grade both the quality of the presentations, and the ability to critique other groups' presentations. These are totally reasonable goals. But I don't see how factoring Group A's critique of Group B into Group B's score makes any sense. What if Group A does a bad job with their critique--shouldn't that affect Group A's score, not Group B?
To me, it seems much simpler to (1) grade the presentations yourself, and (2) grade each individual student on their participation in the critiques.

The only thing I could come up with it this spreadsheet, but I'm not sure it makes logical sense, Am I completely off track?:



Criteria
My Score (1-4)
Opponents Tokens (6 total)
Adjusted Weight
Weighted Score
Final Score (Out of 30)




criterion 1
3
1
=B2 * C2/6
=B2 + D2
=SUM(E2:E8)/32*30


criterion 2
3
1
=B3 * C3/6
=B3 + D3



criterion 3
3
1
=B4 * C4/6
=B4 + D4



criterion 4
3
1
=B5 * C5/6
=B5 + D5



criterion 5
2
0
=B6 * C6/6
=B6 + D6



criterion 6
2
2
=B7 * C7/6
=B7 + D7



criterion 7
2
0
=B8 * C8/6
=B8 + D8




